# onclick redirect to new page with the current image and json data with pure javaScript

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, onclick

I have a page of products with a gallery slider (10 images) with details of shipping and customers review and shipping details, below I have a `Buy` button for user if they want to buy the current product. I am getting the data display from Json file with Ajax Req.

I need to redirect the page to `Purchase Page` on click of a button where user can see the selected product `image` and `product info`.

I want to replace the Purchase item details with the user selected on click of a button with vanilla JavaScript and no jQuery.

```js
function clickinner() {
  // onclick redirect to purchase page
  location.href = '/purchase.html';
  // get the id of the current element and save in a variable
  var currentElement = document.getElementById("product_info").innerHTML;
  var purchase_image = document.getElementById("purchase_image");
  var purschasing_product_info = document.getElementById("purschasing_product_info");
  purchase_image.setAttribute("src", "images/" + data[currentElement].image_path);
  purschasing_product_info.innerHTML = data[currentElement].product_description;
  var obj = {
    purchase_image: purchase_image,
    purschasing_product_info: purschasing_product_info
  };
  // Return obj
  return obj;
};
```

```html
<button class="buy_bttn" onclick="clickinner()" type="button">Buy</button>
<div id="purchase_item_image">
  <img src="images/img1.jpg" id="purchase_image" />
</div>
<div id="purschasing_product_info">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Earum quo cumque illum, rerum repellat autem fugit, quod temporibus consequatur eum quos voluptates alias nesciunt? Sed porro voluptas omnis? Ratione, omnis.
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Your page is GONE when the statement `location.href = '/purchase.html';` has executed .

Comment: Where do you think the `return obj` returns to?

Comment: If you want to show what is in the obj in the next page, you can store the JSON.stringify(obj) in sessionStorage. But then move the location statement to the end of the function